# FBConnect Issues: Authentication and post won't work the first time

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook, fbconnect

I've two issues with Facebook Connect:

1) I use the new Single Sign On Authentication. It works great, but the first time, I authenticate an user with my App when I request the token, i immediately want to post a link to the users wall, but then I get this error:

```
2011-10-11 15:42:44.831 [1717:707] Dialog DidFail With Error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -999.)" UserInfo=0x7487290 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://m.facebook.com/dialog/feed?link=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.it%2Findex.php%3Fid%3D4%26no_cache%3D1%26tx_ttnews%5Btt_news%5D%3D103184&access_token=_test-Z0Ru37mpEAbffAn9n5wlWUaIVOH2tsF8.eyJpdiI6IjYyUXVBOTJKZVVwWjF5bmxZUmluUGcifQ.VxaUq2QcPXUgcYTjvqtnhLcBK27wflAIv3XoNVNcRT6dtQqfJZZ9NdLqLXxPdpBFl1U1DGF8xetLy8TOcLuLmU9l2AQ0JzYKmm9d-7azAYCYiZc51BiXKgHlpzw9Hsplr-tTKAfkXF2oJSOkbeN7UDMyLqDdCyhwiFTdVX3tGzA&app_id=1535027294&redirect_uri=fbconnect%3A%2F%2Fsuccess&user_message_prompt=Teilen&sdk=2&display=touch, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://m.facebook.com/dialog/feed?link=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.it%2Findex.php%3Fid%3D4%26no_cache%3D1%26tx_ttnews%5Btt_news%5D%3D103184&access_token=_Wtest_modifiedF8.eyJpdiI6IjYyUXVBOTJKZVVwWjF5bmxZUmluUGcifQ.VxaUq2QcPXUgcYTjvqtnhLcBK27wflAIv3XoNVNcRT6dtQqfJZZ9NdLqLXxPdpBFl1U1DGF8xetLy8TOcLuLmU9l2AQ0JzYKmm9d-7azAYCYiZc51BiXKgHlpzw9Hsplr-tTKAfkXF2oJSOkbeN7UDMyLqDdCyhwiFTdVX3tGzA&app_id=688535027294&redirect_uri=fbconnect%3A%2F%2Fsuccess&user_message_prompt=Teilen&sdk=2&display=touch}
```

The second time I try to post something to the wall I get a success, there I don't need to request the permissions again. But the first time it always fauls. With the facebook.app installed, but also with the redirect from Safari.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only requested "stream_publish", when requesting also "offline_access" then it works. Seems to be a Facebook issue.

Answer (score 0):

We are seeing the same thing over on [First dialog after authenticating fails immediately and closes dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8002260/first-dialog-after-authenticating-fails-immediately-and-closes-dialog/8016055#comment9863824_8016055)

I know yours was first, but the discussion ended up over on that question.