# iOS Facebook Share Dialog never works the first time

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

For some reason, my Facebook share dialog never works the first time—the dialog window opens up and then disappears, and I get the following error:

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -999.)"
```

The URL that is failing with the error is a standard dialog URL, and if I paste it in my web browser, it displays the share dialog. I'm not doing anything special, just calling:

```
[_facebook dialog:@"feed" andParams:params andDelegate:self];
```

When I call that method again, it works perfectly.

Anyone else running into this? This is on iOS 5, and I'm using the newest version of the SDK.

Comment: possible duplicate of [first dialog after authenticating fails immediately and closes dialog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8002260/first-dialog-after-authenticating-fails-immediately-and-closes-dialog)

Answer (score 1):

Duplicate of [First dialog after authenticating fails immediately and closes dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8002260/first-dialog-after-authenticating-fails-immediately-and-closes-dialog/8016055#comment9863824_8016055)

Short answer, this seems to have appeared in iOS 5. There are a couple sort of nasty workarounds. Good luck!