# First time authorization fails with FBConnect via mobile app

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

After downloading my app from app store (or via OTA) and trying to share via FBConnect SDK, the mobile app is launched but returns almost immediately to the app with error -999, without asking user for authorizations.

After that, clicking on FB share button reopens the mobile app and all goes well, authorizations are asked, my app is called back and display the FB dialog.

That issue only happens once : if I uninstall/reinstall the app and remove the FBapp authorizations from my FB account, all goes well.

I already specified the BundleID/iTunes App ID in the "Native iOS App" menu, and use the last FacebookConnect SDK.

Anyone experienced the same issue ?

Comment: Yeah, here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8002260/first-dialog-after-authenticating-fails-immediately-and-closes-dialog/8016055#comment9863824_8016055

Still haven't completely resolved it, keeps occurring on random devices.

Comment: Thanks, but it is not the exact same issue... Mine don't allow user to authorize at all during the SSO process : The FB mobile app launches but returns immediately to my app without asking for authorizations. On second try it will launch the FB mobile app again and all the process works then well. Sorry if I don't explained it well !

Comment: I'm also seeing this now; in fact, I've given up on SSO. It works inconsistently across devices and Facebook login states. Too unreliable to use in a production app.

Comment: Yeah, I also removed SSO from the app. Thanks for your help :)