# iOS: Facebook Comments Plugin mobile keeps reloading

Tags: ios, facebook, ios5, ios4, ios-simulator

Recently I have been trying to integrate Facebook Social Plugins into a custom UIWebView in iOS for commenting a webpage. I have added the Like Button as well as the Comments plugin. Here is the HTML code I load into the web view:

```
  <html>
    <body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.heretheweb.com" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="240" data-show-faces="false"></div>
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://www.heretheweb.com" data-num-posts="5" data-width="470"></div>
<body>
</html>
```

The first implementation on Monday was sucessfull in 4 platforms, both simulators (iOS 4 and iOS 5), iPhone 3G iOS4 and iPhone 4 iOS 5.
On Tuesday, I kept developing this and I ended up with my custom UIWebView working with no problems in the first three. But on iPhone 4 (iOS 5) the web view kept reloading the same web page over and over again, resulting in the comment box never appearing. That URL is this:

https://m.facebook.com/plugins/comments.php?channel_url=http%3A%2F%2Fstatic.ak.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter.php%3Fversion%3D4%23cb%3Df28c738848%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.heretheweb.com%252Ff3fdf142e8%26domain%3Dwww.heretheweb.com%26relation%3Dparent.parent&href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.heretheweb.com&locale=en_US&mobile=true&numposts=5&sdk=joey&width=470

I don't know what I am doing wrong really, I have cleaned the uiWebView delegate methods, I have check with breakpoints ALL the methods I could override. Nothing... The webpage gets loaded at the beginning, and then it loops trying to load the above URL...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok... solved.
For some strange and weird reason, sometimes when loading the comments web part ONLY in iPhone 4 (not simulator, iPhone 3G or iPad 2) it tries to reload once and once again (the Cache-Control header is set to max-age=0, so it keeps forcing the reload)

The solution was to check the UIWebViewNavigationType, if it's equal to UIWebViewNavigationTypeReload, shouldStartLoadWithRequest: returns NO.

It was REALLY tricky ¬¬

Comment: me neither. i simply get a blank page, with the 3 blue pulsating bars. the initial comments plugin call does not seem to succeed.

Comment: i wonder if the href needs to be legitimized in some way from fb's standpoint, i.e. that when you load the comments plugin on the phone, the href you provide has to offer some proof that it "belongs" to you

Comment: The href has to be the same as the webpage you are trying to comment if I remember correctly

Comment: my href is currently the same as the webpage being loaded, but the problem persists; moreover, after i added the fb admin line to the header of the webpage, the page ceased to work in the simulator, claiming the user was unknown

Comment: What I did was create the web view and then load HTML code with the baseURL = the web I am going to be commenting (loadHTMLString:baseURL:)

Answer (score 5):

There is a bug in the facebook comments plugin that causes an infinite loading loop when the comments plugin is being loaded on Retina enabled devices.

There is a line in one of fb js scripts that goes as follows:

`if(window.devicePixelRatio>1)document.location.reload()`

so if you're accessing the page on a device with a high density screen you are doomed.

I reported the issue [here](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/302285693202310)

I came up with a dirty hack to fix it but think twice before using it, it might stop working at any time.

Note that this approach works only when you embed the plugin in UIWebView, if you have a problem when you're accessing a page in safari there's no other option but to wait for a fix from facebook.

My idea was to 'fix' the js code on the fly as it's getting loaded by a UIWebView.

To process requests on the fly I created my own implementation of NSURLProtocol:

```
<FBCommentsFixingURLProtocol.h>

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface FBCommentsFixingURLProtocol : NSURLProtocol

@end

<FBCommentsFixingURLProtocol.m>
#import "FBCommentsFixingURLProtocol.h"


static NSString *FBCommentsFixingHeader = @"X-FBFix";

@interface FBCommentsFixingURLProtocol () 
@property (nonatomic, readwrite, strong) NSURLRequest *request;
@property (nonatomic, readwrite, strong) NSURLConnection *connection;
@property (nonatomic, readwrite, strong) NSURLResponse *response;

@end

@implementation FBCommentsFixingURLProtocol
@synthesize request = request_;
@synthesize connection = connection_;
@synthesize response = response_;


+ (BOOL)canInitWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
{
    if (([request.URL.scheme isEqualToString:@"https"] || [request.URL.scheme     isEqualToString:@"http"]) && [request.URL.absoluteString rangeOfString:@"facebook.com/plugins/comments.php"].location != NSNotFound &&
    [request valueForHTTPHeaderField:FBCommentsFixingHeader] == nil)
{
    return YES;
}
return NO;
}

+ (NSURLRequest *)canonicalRequestForRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
{
    return request;
}

- (id)initWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
       cachedResponse:(NSCachedURLResponse *)cachedResponse
           client:(id <NSURLProtocolClient>)client
{
    // Modify request so we don't loop
    NSMutableURLRequest *myRequest = [request mutableCopy];
    [myRequest setValue:@"" forHTTPHeaderField:FBCommentsFixingHeader];
    self = [super initWithRequest:myRequest
               cachedResponse:cachedResponse
                       client:client];
    if (self)
    {
       [self setRequest:myRequest];
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)startLoading
{
    NSURLConnection *connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:[self request]
                                                            delegate:self];
    [self setConnection:connection];

}

- (void)stopLoading
{
    [[self connection] cancel];
}


- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    NSString *dataAsString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
     //Just modify the script to prevent it from execution on Retina devices.
    //window.devicePixelRatio = 2 for the Retina Display
    NSString* modified =  [dataAsString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"if(window.devicePixelRatio>1)document.location.reload();" withString:@""];
    NSData* dataMod=[modified dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [[self client] URLProtocol:self didLoadData:dataMod];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    [[self client] URLProtocol:self didFailWithError:error];
    [self setConnection:nil];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    [self setResponse:response];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    [[self client] URLProtocolDidFinishLoading:self];
    [self setConnection:nil];
}


@end
```

And then I registered it in the app delegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
[NSURLProtocol registerClass:[FBCommentsFixingURLProtocol class]];
```

I'm aware that this is a dirty hack but still it works.

Comment: WOW!! AMAZING FIND MY FRIEND O_O!!

Answer (score 0):

I have this same problem under safari/ios mobile, on a web app developed on sencha touch 1,
it work under others browsers and SO, but on this, it keep loading and loading.
I can't find the clue.

Answer (score 0):

Below code is working fine for me

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 400)];
NSString *html = @"<div id=\"fb-root\"></div><script>(function(d, s, id) {var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if (d.getElementById(id)) return;js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;js.src = \"https://connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5\";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script><div class=\"fb-comments\" data-href=\"URL_OF_YOUR_PAGE\" data-numposts=\"5\"></div>";
    [webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://facebook.com"]];
    [self.view addSubview:webView];
```