# Why does Facebook iOS dialog for feed publish disappear after login?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm trying to use the Facebook iOS "feed" dialog call to allow my app's user to share something on their Facebook wall. When the facebook app is not installed, it attempts to let them authenticate within the app (presumably using a web view). The issue is that this dialog just disappears once they authenticate. I was expecting the web view to return to the "feed" sharing view.

How do I detect that they authenticated so that I can re-open the feed dialog?

I've added fbDidLogin to my app delegate, but it's not being called. (I wasn't sure if this would normally be called or not, but I read several people recommending this.)

```
    SBJSON *jsonWriter = [SBJSON new];

    // The action links to be shown with the post in the feed
    NSArray* actionLinks = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                      @"More Videos",@"name",@"http://www.example.com/",@"link", nil], nil];
    NSString *actionLinksStr = [jsonWriter stringWithObject:actionLinks];

    NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   @"Test Caption", @"caption",
                                   @"Test Description", @"description",
                                   @"https://s3.amazonaws.com/example/images/test.png",
                                   @"source",
                                   self.video.blogLink, @"link",
                                   @"01234567890123", @"app_id",
                                   actionLinksStr, @"actions",
                                   nil];
    [delegate facebook].sessionDelegate = delegate;
    [[delegate facebook] dialog:@"feed" andParams:params andDelegate:self];
```

Comment: I also had this problem when I played around with the Facebook sdk a while ago and could find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the issue is the same as those reporting that the dialog disappears immediately for them. There is a bug in the Facebook SDK in regards to handling error -999, [with the solution described in this comment on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9271652/650558).

I finally realized I was having the same issue (albeit manifesting slightly differently), when I started listening to the FBDialogDelegate's method:

```
- (void)dialog:(FBDialog*)dialog didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
```

The error description referenced the -999 error mentioned above, leading me to the answer. Luckily the code checked into github worked flawlessly. I just had to pull it into the SDK codebase and recompile the .a lib file, then include it into my project.

Answer (score 0):

Did you implemented facebook protocol FBSession in your view controller ?
To detect that user is authenticated you have to call isSessionValid:

```
if (![[self.fbAppDelegate facebook] isSessionValid]) {
    NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"publish_stream",@"create_event",@"offline_access", nil];

    [[self.fbAppDelegate facebook] authorize:permissions];

}
```

and authorize inApp:

```
[self authorizeWithFBAppAuth:NO safariAuth:NO];
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is all of this true even if you're not trying to authorize the app to act on behalf of the user, i.e. you just want to allow the user to share on their wall on an as-needed basis?